# Error Con Resta de Fechas en función con JavaScript

Tags: javascript

quisiera ver si alguien me puede ayudar con esta función en donde ingreso dos fechas y quiero sacar cuantos días , meses y años hay , el problema es que cuando ingreso 12 de abril de 2017 y saco la diferencia con la fecha de hoy me sale que hay 3 años pero en verdad deberían ser 4

aquí esta la función:

```
 function diff_years(dt2, dt1) {
        debugger;

        var diff = Math.abs(dt1.getTime() - dt2.getTime());
        var day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

        var days = Math.floor(diff / day);
        days = days ;
        var months = Math.floor(days / 31);
        var years = Math.floor(months / 12);

        return years;

    }
```

Siendo  dt1 = new Date(Date.now());
dt2 = 12/04/2017

si alguien me puede ayudar con esto muchas gracias

Comment: El problema es que en los meses estás dividiendo los días entre `31`, cuando no todos los meses tienen `31` días, si le colocaras `30`, te saldrían los 4 años, aunque el resultado no sería la diferencia exacta, te recomiendo que para el manejo de fechas uses `moment.js`

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta , pero no abría una manera de hacerlo sin agregar moments.js ya que es un proyecto en donde no puedo agregar cdn extras solo puedo usar javascript puro o jquery , cosas de empresas.

Comment: @JulioTobar ya agregué la solución con JS puro, espero te sirva :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que en los meses estás dividiendo los días entre `31`, cuando no todos los meses tienen `31 días`, si le colocaras `30`, te saldrían los 4 años, aunque el resultado no sería la diferencia exacta, te recomiendo que para el manejo de fechas uses moment.js

Te dejo el enlace a su documentación: https://momentjs.com/

```js
let d1 = moment(); // Establece la fecha del día de hoy
let d2 = moment('12-04-2017','DD-MM-YYYY'); // Ingresamos la fecha y el formato que deseamos

let dias = d1.diff(d2, 'days'); // Usamos la función diff para obtener la diferencia en días
let meses = d1.diff(d2, 'months'); // Usamos la función diff para obtener la diferencia en meses
let anios = d1.diff(d2, 'years'); // Usamos la función diff para obtener la diferencia en años

console.log('DÍAS: ' + dias);
console.log('MESES: ' + meses);
console.log('AÑOS: ' + anios);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: sabias que momentjs no esta teniendo soportes, de hecho los mismos desarrolladores la declararon como obsoleta puedes verlo en la pagina

Answer (score 2):

Yo soy un poco estricto en cuanto a no usar momentjs porque siento que en realidad no es de tanta ayuda puesto que lo puedes hacer por ti mismo y evitas importar toda una librería.

Te dejo la solución en JS puro; como verás propongo 2 funciones, una para darte la diferencia entre dos fechas (años + meses + días) y (años | meses | días). Si comparas con momenjs, verás que dan los mismos resultados.

```js
const dateDiff = (start, end) =>{
    let diff = {
        days: 0,
        months: 0,
        years: 0
    };
    
    diff.days = end.getUTCDate() - start.getUTCDate();
    diff.months = end.getUTCMonth() - start.getUTCMonth();
    diff.years = end.getUTCFullYear() - start.getUTCFullYear();
    
    if (diff.days < 0) {
        diff.days += new Date(start.getUTCFullYear(), start.getUTCMonth() + 2, 0).getDate();
        --diff.months;
    }
    if (diff.months < 0) {
        diff.months += 12;
        --diff.years;
    }
    
    console.log(`years: ${diff.years}\nmonths: ${diff.months}\ndays: ${diff.days}`);
    
}

const dateDiff2 = (start, end) =>{
    let diff = {
        days: 0,
        months: 0,
        years: 0
    };
    
    diff.days = Math.floor((end.getTime() - start.getTime()) / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
    diff.years = end.getUTCFullYear() - start.getUTCFullYear();
    diff.months = diff.years * 12  + end.getUTCMonth() - start.getUTCMonth();
    
    console.log(`years: ${diff.years}\nmonths: ${diff.months}\ndays: ${diff.days}`);
    
}
    
dateDiff(new Date(2017, 3, 12), new Date());
dateDiff2(new Date(2017, 3, 12), new Date());
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
    function diff_years(dt2, dt1) {
        //debugger;
    
        //var diff = Math.abs(dt1.getTime() - dt2.getTime());
    
        days = parseInt((dt2.getTime()-dt1.getTime())/(24*3600*1000));
    
        //var day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    
        // los dias son numeros enteros no flotantes...
        //var days = Math.floor(diff / day);
       
    
        // de la fecha obtenemos su a;o y lo restamos
        var years = dt2.getFullYear()-dt1.getFullYear();
        // ahora sacamos los meses
        var months = (dt2.getMonth()+12*dt2.getFullYear())-(dt1.getMonth()+12*dt1.getFullYear());
    
        return {days,months,years};
    
    }
    
    dt1 = new Date(Date.now());
    dt2 = new Date("12/04/2017");
    
    console.log(diff_years(dt1,dt2))
```

Comment: La cantidad de meses y días no son correctos

Comment: la cantidad de dias y meses son correctas... es la cantidad de dias transcurridos desde el 2017 al igual que los meses...

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta , pero no resta los meses y los días y necesito que se reste toda la fecha

Comment: @Bryro Es imposible que si la diferencia en años es `4`, la diferencia en meses sea menor a `48`